# Display all database names

Tags: postgresql, psql

is there any way to display all database names using the host address and port?
Like `SELECT current_database()` which shows currently connected db. I need to display all database names.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a table which shows all databases:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_database;
```